# IIS Server not sending "Cert Authorities" in CertificationRequest

Tags: ssl, mtls

We configured the IIS server to require client's certificate. While we have made it work, I noticed that the IIS server is sending an  Cert Authorities in the `CertificationRequest`. Is there a configuration in IIS to enable that?

Here is the hand shake messages:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
*** ServerHelloDone
```

The problem is if the server does not specify which CA is acceptable. The client assume all CAs are acceptable. We have multiple keys in the keystore, so the client will choose the 'first' one, where there is no definition of 'first'.

Comment: Assuming you have Many-To-One Mappings, you should check rules configured for the Client certificate. Can you please take a look at this link?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication/manytoonemappings/add/rules/add

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is controlled by Registry entry: "SendTrustedIssuerList". Since Windows Server 2012 the default behaviour has changed to "OFF" by default. This entry needs be set to 1.

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786429(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN